# In debug mode, is there a way to break(pause the execution) whereever it is?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

If I put a breakpoint somewhere in the code, it is pausing when the program is about to read that line of code.

Sometimes while the program is running, I want to pause it. I do not know which line of code it is reading currently. Is it possible to pause the execution whereever it is, as if a breakpoint exists there?

Comment: if you want to pause the debuger push the pause button :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to pause the execution whereever it is, as if a
>   breakpoint exists there?

Yes, when *debugging*, these are your options:

- On the **Debug** menu, click **Break All**
- Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>
- Using the GUI, click on the highlighted *pause* icon:

  [image]